# else if statement won't execute on JavaScript when finding a substring in a string

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write Hangman game in HTML and JS. Most of the code works as expected. And then i got stuck.
Somehow i can't get one part of if else statement to work.
line of code:

- } else if (word.includes(userChar)){

will not execute, when similar part of code:

- } else if (guessedLetters.includes(userChar)){

does execute. What i am missing?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hangman</title>
    <style>
        *{
            background-color: bisque;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: xx-large;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        canvas{
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #aaaaaa;
            border-radius: 30px;
        }
        button{
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px #aaaaaa;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 30px;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }
        input{
            border-radius: 30px;
            padding: 7px;
        }
        .label{
            color: rgb(11, 11, 116);
        }
        #userInput{
            text-align: center;
        }
        #messages{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <p align="center">&nbsp;Hangman</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="240px">&nbsp; 
                <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="300"></canvas>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10%" align="right" class="label">&nbsp;Word:</td>
                        <td width="90%" id="word">&nbsp;_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10%" align="right" class="label">&nbsp;Guess:</td>
                        <td width="90%" id="guess">&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" id="userInput" maxlength="1" size="1" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
                            <button type="button" onclick="testLetter()" id="okButton">OK</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10%" align="right" class="label">&nbsp;Guessed:</td>
                        <td width="90%" id="miss">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10%" align="right" class="label">&nbsp;Left:</td>
                        <td width="90%" id="left">&nbsp;7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10%" align="right" class="label">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="90%" id="newGame">
                        <button type="button" onClick="window.location.reload();" id="newGame">New Game</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="messages">Guess a letter in the word!
            <p align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx  = c.getContext("2d");

        var guessNumber = 0;    
        var wrongGuesses = 0;   // for drawing
        var emptyWord = "__________";
        var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", 
            "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
        var englishAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        var missedLetters = [];
        var guessedLetters = "";
        var words = ["axtenvtsey", "herxtyeswy", "ywxgeysyhe"];
        var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
        console.log(word);
        
        var userChar = "";
        function testLetter(){
            var userChar = document.getElementById("userInput").value.toUpperCase();
            console.log(userChar);
            document.getElementById('userInput').value = "";
            document.getElementById("userInput").focus();

            if(userChar == "" || userChar == " "){
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = "Insert Character!";
            } else if(!(englishAlphabet.includes(userChar))){
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = "Illegal Character!";

            } else if (guessedLetters.includes(userChar)){
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = "Already Selected!";
            } else if (word.includes(userChar)){
                console.log("This letter is in gessing word!");
                for (char in word){
                    if (char == userChar){
                    emptyWord += word[char] + " ";
                    }
                }
                console.log(emptyWord);
                document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = word;
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = "Good Guess!";
                guessedLetters += userChar;
                document.getElementById("miss").innerHTML = guessedLetters;
            } else {                
                console.log(word);
                console.log(typeof(word));
                console.log(userChar);
                console.log(typeof(userChar));
                console.log(emptyWord);
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = "Bad Guess!";
                wrongGuesses += 1;
                drawing(wrongGuesses);
                guessedLetters += userChar;
                document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = 7 - wrongGuesses;
                document.getElementById("miss").innerHTML = guessedLetters;
            }

            
        }

        function drawing(wrongGuesses){
            if(wrongGuesses == 1){
                // hanger
                ctx.lineWidth = 7;
                ctx.moveTo(20, 260);
                ctx.lineTo(180, 260);
                ctx.moveTo(160, 260);
                ctx.lineTo(160, 50);
                ctx.lineTo(80, 50);
                ctx.lineTo(80, 60);
                ctx.stroke();
            }                
            
            if(wrongGuesses == 2){
                // head
                ctx.lineWidth = 3;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(80, 70, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke(); 
            }                

            if(wrongGuesses == 3){
                // body
                ctx.moveTo(80, 80);
                ctx.lineTo(80, 140);
                ctx.stroke();
            }                

            if(wrongGuesses == 4){
                // right arm
                ctx.moveTo(80, 90);
                ctx.lineTo(50, 110);
                ctx.stroke();
            }                

            if(wrongGuesses == 5){
                // left arm
                ctx.moveTo(80, 90);
                ctx.lineTo(110, 110);
                ctx.stroke();
            }                

            if(wrongGuesses == 6){
                // right leg
                ctx.moveTo(80, 140);
                ctx.lineTo(50, 170);
                ctx.stroke();
            }                

            if(wrongGuesses == 7){
                // left leg
                ctx.moveTo(80, 140);
                ctx.lineTo(110, 170);
                ctx.stroke();
                document.getElementById("okButton").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = "Game Over!";
            }                
        }        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `words` array contains words in lowercase and your input is being converted to uppercase, as `includes()` is case-sensitive so it's returning false.

You can change your condition to

```
else if (word.includes(userChar.toLowerCase())){ //Compare with lowercase input
```

Or you might create your words in uppercase :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has these two lines:

```
var englishAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var words = ["axtenvtsey", "herxtyeswy", "ywxgeysyhe"];
```

Now, when you get a character, it has to be a capital letter to be in the `englishAlphabet` but it has to be a lower case letter to be in `words`. Obviously it cannot be both, so you want to use something like:

```
word = word.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You!

uppercase/lowercase was the reason to get stuck.

Now it works great! Back to coding.